# Return index of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I want to search only the first column of `myarray` and return the index:

example search for "s1" returns 0, search "s3" returns 1, and so on

javascript

```
myarray = [
['s1', 's2'],
['s3', 's4'],
['s5', 's6']
]
```

Comment: We're are not going to just do this for you.  Show us what, if anything, you attempted to do to solve this, and we will help you make it right.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the help guys...

solution

```
function searchCPL(what, find){
  for(var i= 0, L= what.length; i<L; i++){
    if(what[i][0]=== find) return i;
  }
    return '';
};

searchCPL(myarray, 'value');
```